# How do I convert string '2016/2/9' to datetime?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of events with date time in string format '2016/2/9 02:03:01'.
I use:

```
$d1 = [datetime]::ParseExact('2015/12/19 08:15:32', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', $null)
```

It got FormatException error:

```
以 "3" 引數呼叫 "ParseExact" 時發生例外狀況: "字串未被辨認為有效的 DateTime。"
位於 J:\Qsync\WORKSPACE\SHELL\trypsl101.ps1:310 字元:5
+     $d1 = [datetime]::ParseExact('2016/2/9 02:03:01', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 
$nu ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

How can I parse date string with varying digit length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`MM` is specifically a two digit month, and `dd` is a two digit day (`02`, `09`, respectively).

Use `M` for a month that can be specified with 1 or 2 digits, and `d` for the same thing with day.

```
$d1 = [datetime]::ParseExact('2016/2/9 02:03:01', 'yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss', $null)
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont use get-date simply?

```
$d1=get-date '2015/12/19 08:15:32' 
$d2=get-date '2016/2/9 02:03:01'
```